# Android app crashes when i try to reLogin

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an android app that is connected to an API through retrofit, ive succesfully logged in, if i press back button to return back to the login activity again, if i try re-logging in again, the app crashes and give me a NullPointerException.

here's connection code

```
    private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

    UnifyAuthenticationApiInterface service = this.client.create(UnifyAuthenticationApiInterface.class);
    Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call = service.staffLogin(email, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call,
                               Response<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> response) {

            UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse result = response.body();
            School school = new School();
            com.peterstev.unify.login.Data data = result.getData();
            mySchoolsList = new ArrayList<School>();
            mySchoolsList = data.getSchools();
            staff = data.getStaff();

            gotoHomeActivity();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed @ onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and the goToHomeActivity() is

```
 private void gotoHomeActivity() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if (mySchoolsList.size() > 1) {
        schoolsListView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
        schoolsArrayAdapter = new SchoolListAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mySchoolsList);
        schoolsListView.setAdapter(schoolsArrayAdapter);

        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(schoolsListView);
        dialog.setTitle("Welcome " + staff.getFullName());
        dialog.show();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

the NullPointerException gets thrown at

```
com.peterstev.unify.login.Data data = result.getData();
```

at first, it gets the data n succesfully logs in, but when i use the back button n try to log in again it crashes.

Comment: None can tell what your backend call returns. Place breakpoint in line that causes NPE and run in debug mode. Then just check why result is null. Maybe some kind of protection for calling login too often. Try to recreate this situation with Postman or similar tool.

Comment: Are you clearing all data on clicking the back button? @Light

Comment: i'm not clearing any data. or do i have to recreate the activity when i go back ? @Partha

Comment: @3mpty with postman here's the json file

Comment: {
  "data": {
    "staff": {
      "school_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "api_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "full_name": "Peters Light"
    },
    "schools": [
      {
        "name": "Some Secondary School",
        "api_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
} postman returns the data in this json format, the i convert to POJO using http://jsonschema2pojo.org with gson as the output annotation style. you can go ahead n try it @3mpty

Comment: @Light check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugger is your answer - check if you aren't loosing any data when going back - maybe you're storing login params somewhere in activity class but you're not saving instance state properly and second request is triggered without necessary data. Check state of variables just before calling your request first and second time.

In situation like that always best bet to place breakpoint and trigger your work step by step. You cannot be good developer without debugger skills.

Answer (score 0):

I think for some reason, the data object wasn't receiving the result when i used the back button to navigate to the parent activity. so i used and if condition to make it get the required data.

```
 private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

    UnifyAuthenticationApiInterface service = this.client.create(UnifyAuthenticationApiInterface.class);
    Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call = service.staffLogin(email, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call,
                               Response<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse result = response.body();
                School school = new School();
                data = result.getData();
                if(data == null) {
                    try{
                        this.onResponse(call, response);
                    }catch(NullPointerException NPE){
                        Log.d("NPE", NPE.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                mySchoolsList = new ArrayList<School>();
                mySchoolsList = data.getSchools();
                staff = data.getStaff();

                gotoHomeActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UnifyAuthenticationApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed @ onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```